Why my query to select from Oracle database turn to text (blank query) every time i run it
I try to run query from Power Bi by usng Power Query and i want to use parameter like the code below
let
    employeeID = 1,  
    Query = "SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name FROM employees_1 WHERE employee_id = " & Number.ToText(employeeID),  
    Source = Oracle.Database("//localhost:1521/ORCL", [HierarchicalNavigation=true, Query=Query])
in 
    Source

And every time  i run it, it turn to a blank query like the picture
(https://i.sstatic.net/ihXTzKj8.png)
I try to sreach and still dont know why. Please, help me to fix it.

open the advanced editor and paste the code in it.


Thank you so much, it worked

you are welcome
